# Optimistic RegEx Matching for User Text Entry

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a text entry application that uses regular expressions to validate user input.  The goal is to allow keypresses that fit a certain RegEx while rejecting invalid characters.  One issue I've run into is that when a user starts inputting information they may create a string that doesn't *yet* match the given regex, but could cause a match in the future.  These strings get erroneously rejected.  Here's an example - given the following regex for inputting date information:

`(0?[1-9]|10|11|12)/(0?[1-9]|[12]\\d|30|31)/\\d{2}\\d{2}`

A user may begin entering "1/" which could be a valid date, but `RegEx.IsMatch()` will return false and my code ends up rejecting the string.  Is there a way to "optimistically" test strings against a regular expression so that possible or partial matches are allowed?

Bonus:  For this RegEx in particular there are some sequences which cause required characters.  For example, if the user types "2/15" the only possible valid character they could enter next is "/".  Is it possible to detect those scenarios so that the required characters could be automatically entered for the user to ease input?

Comment: Is there a reason you're checking at each keystroke rather than when the user leaves the field? Trying to validate as the user types is generally very difficult, and ends up being very annoying to the user when he wants to edit.

Comment: Remember the "del" key :-) What happens when the user goes to char 0 and press del?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is anchor your RegExp (i.e. adding ^ and $, as in start/end of line) and make some component optionnal for validation, but strictly defined if present.
Something looking like this:

```
^(0?[1-9]|10|11|12)(/((0?[1-9]|[12]\\d|30|31)(/(\\d{2}(\\d{2})?)?)?)?)?$
```

I do realize it looks horrible but as far as I know there is no way to tell the regexp engine to validate as long as the string satisfies the beginning of the regexp pattern.

In my opinion, the best way to achieve what you want to do is to create separate inputs for day/month/date and check their value when leaving the text field.
 It also provides a better visibility and user-experience, as I believe no one likes to be prevented from typing certain characters into a text field with or without noticing them disappear as they type or having slashes inserted automatically and without notice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used and app or form that worked that way, simply refusing to accept any keypress it didn't like?  If the answer is Yes, did it blow an electronic raspberry each time you pressed a wrong key?

If you really need to validate the input before the form is submitted, use a passive feedback mechanism like a red border around the textfield that disappears the regex matches the input.  Also, make sure there's a Help button or a tooltip nearby to provide *constructive* feedback.

Of course, the best option would be to use a dedicated control like a date-entry widget.  But whatever you do, don't do it in such a a way that it feels like you're playing guessing games with the user.